# Charge accumulation at the boundary of two dielectrics in a capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, boundary-conditions, dielectric

Say we have a capacitor filled with two dielectrics of different constants. The two charged plates of the capacitor are +V and -V. Does charge accumulate at the boundary of the dielectrics? In my simulations, there is a discontinuity in the flux density / Ɛ0 but does this imply a discontinuity in the potential. Shouldn't the potential be continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential is the integral, $\int{\vec E}\cdot{\vec{dr}}$, which is continuous, even at a discontinuity in $\vec E$.

Comment: Would there be a discontinuity in electric flux (and hence charge on the boundary)? I understand that this discontinuity does not mean that potential is non-continuous now

Comment: D is continuous.  Since $\epsilon$ is discontinuous, E will be discontinuous, and there will be surface charge at the boundary.

Comment: If D is continuous how can we have a surface charge at the boundary? Wouldn't this imply that we have no jump in D and so no surface charge due to boundary conditions

Comment: Of course.  I should have said - but there will be no surface charge.